Parquet with array with nested structure in Flink
I am using Apache Flink to process Parquet files, and I have a schema that includes a nested structure. The structure works well when reading simple types, but I am encountering an issue with Flink's Parquet reader when handling nested arrays (or lists) of RowType. Here is my RowType definition and the corresponding Parquet schema.
RowType:
public static final RowType TYPE = RowType.of(
        new LogicalType[]{
                new VarCharType(),
                new ArrayType(ITEMS)
        },
        new String[]{
                "id", "orders"
        }
);

public static final RowType ITEMS = RowType.of(
        new LogicalType[]{
                new VarCharType(),
                new VarCharType(),
                new VarCharType()
        },
        new String[]{"item_id", "item_name", "item_price"}
);

Parquet schema:
message output_scheme {
    required binary id (STRING);
    required group orders (LIST) {
        repeated group array {
            required binary item_id (STRING);
            required binary item_name (STRING);
            required binary item_price (STRING);
        }
    }
}

I attempt to read the Parquet file using the following code in Flink:
RowType rowType = RowScheme.TYPE;
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("source");
String resourceFolderPath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toString();

BulkFormat<RowData, FileSourceSplit> bulkFormat = ParquetColumnarRowInputFormat.createPartitionedFormat(
        new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration(),
        rowType,
        InternalTypeInfo.of(rowType),
        List.of("id"),
        PartitionFieldExtractor.forFileSystem("partition"),
        500,
        true,
        true
);

FileSource<RowData> source = FileSource.forBulkFileFormat(
                bulkFormat,
                new Path(resourceFolderPath)
        )
        .monitorContinuously(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
        .build();

var dataStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Source")
        .map(new ParquetMapFunction())
        .name("Source");
env.execute();

When I run this code, I receive the following error:

org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(PekkoInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1267)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(ScalaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:310)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:307)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:234)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(ScalaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:629)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:34)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:285)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:276)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:488)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(PekkoRpcActor.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:168)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: One or more fetchers have encountered exception
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcherManager.checkErrors(SplitFetcherManager.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.getNextFetch(SourceReaderBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:858)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:932)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SplitFetcher thread 0 received unexpected exception while polling the records
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.run(SplitFetcher.java:117)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at org.apache.parquet.schema.GroupType.getType(GroupType.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.ParquetSplitReaderUtil.createWritableColumnVector(ParquetSplitReaderUtil.java:572)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.ParquetSplitReaderUtil.createWritableColumnVector(ParquetSplitReaderUtil.java:522)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createWritableVectors(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReaderBatch(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:278)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createPoolOfBatches(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.checkSplitOrStartNext(FileSourceSplitReader.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.fetch(FileSourceSplitReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:165)
    ... 6 more

It seems like the Parquet reader does not support nested row types (like arrays of complex records).
I also have tried to update RowType scheme to include array or RowType

public static final RowType TYPE = RowType.of(
        new LogicalType[]{
                new VarCharType(),
                ITEMS_ROWTYPE
        },
        new String[]{
                "id", "orders"
        }
);

public static final RowType ITEMS = RowType.of(
        new LogicalType[]{
                new VarCharType(),
                new VarCharType(),
                new VarCharType()
        },
        new String[]{"item_id", "item_name", "item_price"}
);

public static final RowType ITEMS_ROWTYPE = RowType.of(
        new LogicalType[]{
                new ArrayType(ITEMS)
        },
        new String[]{"array"}
);

But getting this error
Unsupported type in the list: ROW<`item_id` VARCHAR(1), `item_name` VARCHAR(1), `item_price` VARCHAR(1)>



org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(PekkoInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1267)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(ScalaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:310)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:307)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:234)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ScalaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(ScalaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:629)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:34)
    at org.apache.pekko.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:73)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:285)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:276)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:488)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(PekkoRpcActor.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:307)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:168)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: One or more fetchers have encountered exception
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcherManager.checkErrors(SplitFetcherManager.java:263)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.getNextFetch(SourceReaderBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:858)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:953)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:932)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SplitFetcher thread 0 received unexpected exception while polling the records
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.run(SplitFetcher.java:117)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported type in the list: ROW<`item_id` VARCHAR(1), `item_name` VARCHAR(1), `item_price` VARCHAR(1)>
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.reader.ArrayColumnReader.dictionaryDecodeValue(ArrayColumnReader.java:220)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.reader.ArrayColumnReader.collectDataFromParquetPage(ArrayColumnReader.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.reader.ArrayColumnReader.readToVector(ArrayColumnReader.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.reader.RowColumnReader.readToVector(RowColumnReader.java:42)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat$ParquetReader.nextBatch(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:399)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat$ParquetReader.readBatch(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:367)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.fetch(FileSourceSplitReader.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:165)
    ... 6 more


flink version 1.18
Question:

How can I configure Flink to properly read nested RowType in Array from Parquet?

